# Fetch data from external api json and listing table

Tags: reactjs, json, fetch

I am trying to do Fetch and collect the data to display it in a list of tables, I manage to collect the information well but only when I look at a particular entry.

Could someone help me understand this.

Example: https://demo.webuho.com/wp-json/frm/v2/entries/2 
Number **/entries/2** corresponds to a completed record of a form.

The information is displayed like this:

```
{
  "id": "2",
  "item_key": "30ow9",
  "name": "KARTMILLER",
  "meta": {
    "guildname": "KARTMILLER",
    "guildregion": "EUROPE",
    "guildmaster": "OREYITT",
    "guildlinks-value": [
      "Discord"
    ],
  "guildtype": "Only PVE"
}
```

The Result is:
[Result of the individual entry.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0djds.png)

I collect this information well, but when the records are nested in a single url I don't know how to obtain them.

https://demo.webuho.com/wp-json/frm/v2/entries

```
{
  "9aduj": {
    "id": "1",
    "item_key": "9aduj",
    "name": "KARTMILLER XXX",
    "meta": {
      "guildname": "KARTMILLER XXX",
      "guildregion": "NORTH AMERICA",
      "guildmaster": "OREYITT22",
      "guildlinks-value": [
        "Discord"
      ],
      "guildtype": "Only PVE",
    }
  },
  "30ow9": {
    "id": "2",
    "item_key": "30ow9",
    "name": "KARTMILLER",
    "meta": {
      "guildname": "KARTMILLER",
      "guildregion": "EUROPE",
      "guildmaster": "OREYITT",
      "guildlinks-value": [
        "Discord"
      ],
      "guildtype": "Only PVE"
    }
  }
}
```

And result for all entries is:
[Result when I want to see all entries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBEIa.png)

My code in React to do the Fetch is as follows:

```
{guildList.map((guild, id) => (
<tr key={id.guild}>
   <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
      <div className="flex items-center">
         {guild.guildname}
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
))}
```

```js
    const [guildData, setGuilds] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        getGuildsInfo();
    }, []);

    const params = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'content-type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('API-KEY'),
        }
    };
    const getGuildsInfo = async () => {
        const response = await fetch("https://xxxxxxxx/wp-json/frm/v2/entries", params);
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        setUserData(jsonData);

    };
```

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not totally sure what your issue is. If you're receiving the data as an array, all you need to do is map over it and list it out, or probably better make a component which does that for you. You can read about rendering arrays [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html). The only issue I see with this code is that {id.guild} is not a valid key. Unless there's an issue with code you haven't posted there shouldn't be any problems.

Answer (score 0):

```
{guildList.map((guild, id) => (
<tr key={id}>
   <td className="px-6 py-4 whitespace-nowrap">
      <div className="flex items-center">
         {guild.meta.guildname}
      </div>
   </td>
</tr>
))}
```